# msbuild compiler %PATH%

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msbuild

I wish to build my solution using an alternative toolset (cl.exe, link.exe and so on...) by changing the PATH environment variable.

When I build the solution using "devenv MySolution.sln" it uses the alternative toolset correctly (calling the alternative cl.exe instead of Visual C++ cl.exe). When I build it using MSBuild, it uses the Visual C++ compiler anyway, ignoring my setting of PATH.

Is there any solution to this problem? Does anybody know how can I make MSBuild invoke the compiler by resolving %PATH% (without modifying all my project and solution files, of course).

Comment: Do you plan to use VS2008's toolset? If so you should use multi-targeting, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx

Comment: You will have to change the VC++ directories + Executable directories setting in the project, putting your custom path first.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [VCBuild Task Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xcy2245%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you should be able to set the `ToolPath` parameter to the desired path of your alternative toolset.

*Admittedly this isn't as comfortable as setting the PATH environment variable and I didn't try it since I don't have VC++ at hand right now.**

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 uses MSBuild instead of VCBuild for C++ projects. Therefore, I don't think this answer helps much.

Comment: I'm refering to the MSBuild 3.5 VCBuild Task, so I think it should solve the actual problem; but as I said I didn't yet have the oppurtunity to test it.